# $f : I → R^2$, why does the supremum exist?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, metric-spaces, supremum-and-infimum

set $f : I → R^2$, why does the supremum $|f(x)|$ s.t. $x\in I$  exist? $f$ is continuous and $I=[0,1]$

I can show that this is the case when using $R$.

Since $f$ is continuous and closed intervals are compact -> that the supremum exists by the Extreme Value Theorem.

Comment: The function $x \mapsto |f(x)|$ is continuous map from $I$ to $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: @copper.hat Can I split the function $f$ into $f_1$ and $f_2$ , and since they both have a supremum can I conclude that $f$ has a supremum in $\mathbb R^2$?

Comment: $f$ has values in $\mathbb{R}^2$, how do you define an order there?

Comment: This whole exerice is to do with Hilbert space. So the $I:[0,1]$ fills $[0,1] \times [0,1]$

Comment: You lost me there. The function $\phi:[0,1] \to \mathbb{R}$ defined by $\phi(x) = |f(x)|$ is a continuous function on a compact set hence it has a maximum.

Comment: @copper.hat I know that it has a maximum in $\mathbb R$, but does it also have a maximum in $\mathbb R^2?$

Comment: I have no idea what you are asking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've got two functions in play:

- $f:I\to R^2$
- $g : R^2 \to R$, given by $g(x) = \left| x \right|$

So what you're actually looking to do is show that $g \circ f$ assumes a maximum value on $I$. But $g \circ f$ is a function from $I$ to $R$, and you already know this is the case for such functions so long as $g \circ f$ is continuous. You know $f$ is continuous, hence you need only prove that $g$ is also continuous (it is).

Answer (score 0):

If you can already show the analogous property of functions $I\rightarrow\mathbb R$, then the only step remaining is to note that the function $g:\mathbb R^2\rightarrow\mathbb R$ taking vectors $v$ to their norm $|v|$ is continuous. This is easily proven by the triangle inequality. Then, we see that the map taking $x$ to $|f(x)|$ is simply the composition $g\circ f$ and hence must be continuous. Moreover, $g\circ f$ is a function $I\rightarrow\mathbb R$ and so has a maximum value, as you are already familiar with.